# connect to DataBase .mdf (Class Labrary) from web app

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013, connection-string, mdf

I want to connect to DB .mdf from web Application which is located in ClassLabrary Project.

When I write:

```
    private const string URL = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                        AttachDbFilename=*FULL PATH*;
                        Integrated Security=True";
```

it works.

But when I write:

```
    private const string URL = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                        AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LocalDB.mdf;
                        Integrated Security=True";
```

it doesnt work.

The error is : "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

I want that the connectionString will not be specific on one computer.
Someone have a suggest how I can solve it?

the project are locate under the same solution
I works on visual studio 2013
thanks